# ​Daily​ average number of staying guests ​for a specific date range

Tags: sql

```
ID   Event     Date
101  in    08/26/2019
101  out   08/28/2019
102  in    08/27/2019
102  out   09/01/2019
```

Every customer has 2 entries, one for check-in and one for check out. 
I have to find out the daily average number of guests staying in a date range.

Comment: Just so there is no confusion, can you share the desired output from the above input

Comment: `SQL` is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Which dbms is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Read this.

Comment: date function are db dependant so please  tell use which db you are really using  .. and the expected  output too

Answer (score 0):

In the query below, any dates that do not exist in your data (no check-ins or check-outs) will not be counted when calculating your average. This should be fine if you know you will have at least one event for each date.

```
set @checkin_count = 0;
set @checkout_count = 0;
set @start_date = '2019-08-26';
set @end_date = '2019-09-02';
set @date_diff = datediff(@end_date,@start_date);
set @date_counter = 0;
select sum(current_guest_count)/datediff(@end_date,@start_date) as avg_num_of_stays
from (
  select
  ID
  ,Event
  ,case
  when Event = 'in' then @checkin_count := @checkin_count + 1
  when Event = 'out' then @checkout_count := @checkout_count + 1
  end
  ,(@checkin_count - @checkout_count) as current_guest_count
  ,Date
  from stays
  order by Date asc
) a
where Date between @start_date and @end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot to convert `in` and `out` into `columns` then you can easily find out the average. I have found the total number of a customer staying on each day:

```
    SELECT
    D.DATES,
    COUNT(CASE
        WHEN OUR_DATA.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) CUSTOMERS_PER_DAY
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ID,
                    EVENT,
                    DATE
                FROM
                    YOUR_TABLE
            ) PIVOT (
                MAX ( DATE )
                FOR EVENT
                IN ( 'in' AS IN_DATE, 'out' AS OUT_DATE )
            )
    ) OUR_DATA
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT
            DATE_RANGE_START + LEVEL AS DATES
        FROM
            DUAL
        CONNECT BY
            LEVEL <= DATE_RANGE_END - DATE_RANGE_START
    ) D ON ( D.DATES BETWEEN IN_DATE AND OUT_DATE )
GROUP BY
    D.DATES
```

**Note:** `DATES` subquery is used to fetch all the days between range start and end. It is used in case no customer checked in or out on a specific day and still, we need to count the customer as "stayed" because customer checked in before day and out after few days.

Cheers!!

Comment: If any of the answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This might send you in the right direction:

```
with data as (
    select ID, min(Date) as checkin, max(Date) as checkout
    from T group by ID /* assumes only one stay per customer */
)
select
    sum(
        datediff(days,
            case when @start > checkin then @start else checkin end,
            case when @end < checkout then @end else checkout end
        ) - 1 /* assumes checkout day isn't counted */
    ) * 1.0 / (datediff(days, @start, @end) - 1)
from data
where @start < checkout and @end > checkin;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the solution you are looking for. The steps are (1) create a list of dates from the start date to the end date, (2) create a row for each customer with an in and out date, (3) using outer join count the number of customers for each day.

```
with daylist as
( 
select convert(datetime, "08/22/2019") as days
union all
select dateadd(dd, 1, days)
from daylist
where days < convert(datetime, "09/03/2019")
)
select d.days, sum(case when t.id is null then 0 else 1 end)
from daylist d
left join
    (
    select a.id, a.dait as indate, b.dait as outdate
    from yourtable a
    inner join yourtable b on a.id = b.id
    where a.event = "in"
    and b.event = "out"
    ) t
on d.days between convert(datetime, t.indate) and convert(datetime, t.outdate)
group by d.days
```